# Read Htmlbody of outlook .msg file with ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, outlook

In our web Application our clients are use to attach .msg (outlook email) as a reference.

What I am trying to do is show the  html body of .msg file in a .aspx page

Below code is working fine with VS 2010 IDE but when I deploy on same machine I am getting following Error,

Please Help me

```
   Public Shared Function GetMessageHTML(ByVal MsgPath As String) As String

    Dim app As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application = Nothing
    Dim session As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace = Nothing
    Dim mail As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem = Nothing
    Dim HtmlBody As String = String.Empty
    Dim NewHTMLBody As String = String.Empty

    Try
        app = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application()
        session = app.Session
        mail = DirectCast(session.OpenSharedItem(MsgPath.Trim()), Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)
        HtmlBody = mail.HTMLBody

        TryCast(mail, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem).Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlInspectorClose.olDiscard)

        TryCast(app, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._Application).Quit()
        Try
            My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(HtmlFName, NewHTMLBody, False)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return "File Write Exception " & ex.Message
        End Try

    Catch ex As System.Exception
        Return "Read Exception " & ex.Message
    Finally
        If mail IsNot Nothing Then
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(mail)
        End If
        If session IsNot Nothing Then
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(session)
        End If
        If app IsNot Nothing Then
            System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.FinalReleaseComObject(app)
        End If
    End Try

    Return HtmlFName
End Function
```

Above Code read .msg file and save html body content to a new .html file then I am showing that new html in an IFrame.

I am using Windows 7 with VS 2010 and it work perfectly in development environment but when I publish on localhost (same machine) I am getting below error

[image: Error]

Can any one guide me how to fix this issue ? I have given Full Permission on physical folder to user IIS_IUSRS